# jquery (or css) every second element with class

Tags: jquery, html, css

It doesnt seem to be possible to get every second element with a specific class name in either jquery or css.

Specfically im trying the nth-child selector in both like so:

```
$( ".mylist li.myitem:nth-child(2n)")
```

If i have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="myitem">Item 1</li>
    <li class="myitem">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class="myitem">Item 4</li>
    <li class="myitem">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to target item 2 and item 5.

(this list above is a sample, it is the underlying technique i need to get i.e. to get every second element with a specific class)
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:odd` selector

```
$("ul li.myitem:odd").addClass('red');
```

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/Uhv27/

Comment: This only works for 2 and then 5. After that it colors every other item not every two. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Uhv27/1/)

Comment: @Pow-Ian this is exactly the expected result EDIT: "After that it colors every other item not every two" not on chrome, which browser are you testing it?

Comment: @Pow-Ian I think, this is what OP is looking for `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/8F3dh/1/

Comment: I took every second element to mean the second then the fifth then the seventh etc.

Comment: OP asked every other item with `.myitem` class not every `li`

Comment: Every other item would be 2 then 4 then 6, not 2 then 5 then 8

Comment: @Pow-Ian Look at html again.... Item 3 is not a `.myitem` so your script should just skip that li

Comment: @Pow-Ian i didn't know who upvoted your last comment but seems quite rude imo ;)

Comment: it's not rude, they are simply agreeing with the fact that I should feel dumb. I totally missed a piece of the question and then tried to show I was right. I agree with the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can do this with CSS:

```
.myitem + .myitem {
   /*Styles Here*/
}
```

With this you target an element with class `myitem` that is right after another with class `myitem`.

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryLAr/)**

Comment: I didn't notice the third `li`. I withdrew my comment.

Comment: Would this work for elements that were not directly next to each other?

Comment: @MartyWallace no it won't

Comment: @A.Wolff - you posted a comment which had an answer in it that works.  Can you add as an answer and I will accept

Comment: @MartyWallace what is wrong with Mohammad's answer?

Comment: @MartyWallace ya and i guess it is your best bet

Comment: As the comments no it won't @MartyWallace this question was posted before you edit the post ...

Answer (score 1):

For elements that are not siblings, you could use the index

```
var items = $('.myitem');

items.filter(function() {
    return items.index(this) % 2;
}).css('color','red');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4H8dy/1/)

Comment: you don't really need index right?! http://jsfiddle.net/4H8dy/2/ Anyway +1 because comparing to :odd, you can decide here to set all 3, 4, 5, etc...

Comment: @A.Wolff - There you go, I was complicating things as I was stuck on the index of the element in the current collection to ignore any other elements in between, but the loops index would of course be exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector `:odd` will return every second element in the order of its appearance in the document. In your case...

```
$('.myitem:odd')
```

will return

```
[<li class=​"myitem">​Item 2​</li>​, <li class=​"myitem">​Item 5​</li>​]
```

Comment: Elaborate your answer